# Python3 slicing negative stop and negative step

Tags: python, python-3.x

Please see below statements,  from 1 to 4, this all makes sense and is inline to what I know about python slicing. But I can't explain the outcome of Statement no 5. Can anyone help explain the outcome of statement 5 ...

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

#1
print(x[::-2]) 
# prints [10, 8, 6, 4, 2]

#2
print(x[:-2])
# prints [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

#3
print(x[:-2][::-2])
# prints [8, 6, 4, 2]

#4
print(x[::-2][:-2])
# prints [10, 8, 6]

#5 (please explain this one)
print(x[:-2:-2])
#prints [10]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see from example #1, when you have a negative step value but leave off the start, it works backward starting at the last.  So the first value is the last one in the `list`, which is `10` at index `-1`.

The end is given as `-2`, which means the second from the last.  But since your step is `-2`, the next in the sequence would be index `-3` which is past `-2`.  So the sequence ends immediately.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

```
#5 (please explain this one)
print(x[:-2:-2])
#prints [10]
```

It just starts from 0 index and stop at -2(means it will go upto third term from last)
then it starts incrementing by -2.
Slice syntax:

```
x[start:stop:step]
```

So definitely 10 will be printed

Comment: @Prabhash Did U get it?

Comment: so in your answer .. when you explained 5th statement .. you are saying it does  this x[0:-2][::-2] ?

Comment: In 4th one, you are doing slicing two times